# Access stage from arbitrary location

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, stage

Say I've got a utility class in which I would like to access the stage (in order to get the frameRate).

I don't particularly want to force the user to pass in the stage to each method or set a static property on my class before using it.

Is there any way to get ahold of the stage without it being passed in? All I need is the frameRate!

Comment: I think I'll just measure the intervals between ENTER_FRAME events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the framerate as a public static variable or public constant in your main document class (or where ever else a reference to the stage is available) then call that static variable from your utility class:

**Document Class**

```
package
{
    //Imports
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;

    //Class
    [SWF(width = "1000", height = "500", BackgroundColor = "0x555555")]
    public class DocumentClass extends Sprite
    {
        //Static Variables
        public static var FRAME_RATE:uint;

        //Constructor
        public function DocumentClass()
        {
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
            stage.frameRate = FRAME_RATE = 60;

            //...
        }
    }
}
```

**Utility Class**

```
package
{
    //Imports
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;

    //Class
    public class UtilityClass extends EventDispatcher
    {
        //Constructor
        public function UtilityClass()
        {
            trace("SWF Frame Rate: " + DocumentClass.FRAME_RATE);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**[EDIT]:**

---

in your case where you don't have direct access to the stage you could have your users pass the `stage.frameRate` value to the constructor of your utility class, but i'm sure you will agree this approach isn't very elegant.  i think that your idea to measure the intervals between ENTER_FRAME events is the best solution.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have control over the document class. My utility is compiled to an independent SWC.

Comment: Looks like getting the stage isn't possible without someone giving it to me, either directly or indirectly. Oh well!

Comment: it's because your utility class isn't a display object so there is no access to the stage.  another possible solution is to make your utility class a display object, or force the uses to add a blank display object to the display list.  this approach is really ghetto, but accessing the stage via display objects is the only common way to access properties of the stage.

Comment: here's another option i found - although it doesn't require the user to pass the framerate value to your utility class, it does require your utility class be passed `loaderInfo` and be instantiated from a display object currently on the display list:  http://blog.natebeck.net/2010/12/tip-of-the-day-getting-a-swfs-background-color/  and here's the code: https://github.com/ZaaLabs/ZaaUtils/blob/master/src/com/zaalabs/utils/SwfData.as

Answer (score 0):

If you have no plans to change the framerate runtime it can be nice to use a Settings class containing all Global values you could use throughout your project.

Settings.as

```
package
{
    public class Settings
    {

        public static const FRAMERATE : int = 30;
        public static const BUILD : String = "build 0.12";
        public static const APPLICATION_WIDTH : int = 800;
        public static const APPLICATION_HEIGHT : int = 800;

    }
}
```

Main.as

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {

        public function Main()
        {
            stage.frameRate = Settings.FRAMERATE;
        }

    }
}
```